# ActivityCompat.requestPermissions Doesn't Show Dialog in Android

Tags: android, permissions

Android Version on Phone : 6.0.1 ( Android marshmallow ) 
Android target SDK Version 25
I Calling the ActivityCompat.requestPermissions in Android button but doesn't show dialog to Procced it

**Button**

```
printrequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try{

            verifyStoragePermissions(SickFragmentId.this);
        }
        catch(Exception e ){
            Log.e("LoginActv: Save Block", e.getMessage());
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

        String req = textViewReqNo.getText().toString();
        String name = Name.getText().toString();
        String branch = Branch.getText().toString();
        String departement_position = Departement_Position.getText().toString();
        String status = Status.getText().toString();
        String description = Description.getText().toString();
        String type = Status.getText().toString();
        String date = Date.getText().toString();

        Intent showId = new Intent(SickFragmentId.this, print.class);
        startActivity(showId);

    }
});
```

**And i put the code in Print.java**

```
public class print extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        Log.e("Permission value", permission + " ");
        if (permission != 1) {
            Log.e("Permission ask", "Asking, permission not granted");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,  String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


        if (requestCode == 200) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Log.e("PERResult", "Granted");

                String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                        + "/PDF/" + "AldanRIZKISANTOSA.pdf";

                Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

                // Create Directory in External Storage
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/PDF");
                myDir.mkdirs();

                // Create Pdf Writer for Writting into New Created Document
                try {
                    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));

                    // Open Document for Writting into document
                    document.open();

                    // User Define Method
                    addMetaData(document);
                    addTitlePage(document);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (DocumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Close Document after writting all content
                document.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "PDF File is Created. Location : " + FILE,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } else {
                Log.e("PERResult", "Denied");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PERMISSION_DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    // Set PDF document Properties
    public void addMetaData(Document document)

    {
        document.addTitle("RESUME");
        document.addSubject("Person Info");
        document.addKeywords("Personal, Education, Skills");
        document.addAuthor("TAG");
        document.addCreator("TAG");
    }

    public void addTitlePage(Document document) throws DocumentException {
        // Font Style for Document
        Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);
        Font titleFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 22, Font.BOLD
                | Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.GRAY);
        Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD);
        Font normal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL);

        // Start New Paragraph
        Paragraph prHead = new Paragraph();
        // Set Font in this Paragraph
        prHead.setFont(titleFont);
        // Add item into Paragraph
        prHead.add("RESUME – Name\n");

        // Create Table into Document with 1 Row
        PdfPTable myTable = new PdfPTable(1);
        // 100.0f mean width of table is same as Document size
        myTable.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);

        // Create New Cell into Table
        PdfPCell myCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(""));
        myCell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);

        // Add Cell into Table
        myTable.addCell(myCell);

        prHead.setFont(catFont);
        prHead.add("\nName1 Name2\n");
        prHead.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        // Add all above details into Document
        document.add(prHead);
        document.add(myTable);

        document.add(myTable);

        // Now Start another New Paragraph
        Paragraph prPersinalInfo = new Paragraph();
        prPersinalInfo.setFont(smallBold);
        prPersinalInfo.add("Address 1\n");
        prPersinalInfo.add("Address 2\n");
        prPersinalInfo.add("City: SanFran. State: CA\n");
        prPersinalInfo.add("Country: USA Zip Code: 000001\n");
        prPersinalInfo
                .add("Mobile: 9999999999 Fax: 1111111 Email: john_pit@gmail.com \n");

        prPersinalInfo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

        document.add(prPersinalInfo);
        document.add(myTable);

        document.add(myTable);

        Paragraph prProfile = new Paragraph();
        prProfile.setFont(smallBold);
        prProfile.add("\n \n Profile : \n ");
        prProfile.setFont(normal);
        prProfile
                .add("\nI am Mr. XYZ. I am Android Application Developer at TAG.");

        prProfile.setFont(smallBold);
        document.add(prProfile);

        // Create new Page in PDF
        document.newPage();
    }
}
```

**But the Dialog for permission doesn't show**

Before i use ActivityCompat.requestPermissions i have error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/PDF/Name.pdf (Permission denied)
```

After i use ActivityCompat.requestPermission i have error

```
E/Permission value: -1
E/Permission ask: Asking, permission not granted
```

Comment: Because you request permission dialog and after that immediately start new activity. It prevents showing dialog. You should request permission, wait result and only after that start new activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( hasPermissionWriteExternalStorage()){
        //do smth
    }


    public boolean hasPermissionWriteExternalStorage() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            return true;
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {case PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //do smth             
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Access Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in `onCreate()` method;

```
requestStoragePermission();
```

and define this method;

```
 private void requestStoragePermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
        //Here you can explain why you need this permission
        //Explain here why you need this permission
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
    }
    //And finally ask for the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
            {
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                    android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
            }, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);


}
//This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    //Checking the request code of our request
    if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        //If permission is granted
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can read the storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```